# Smart way to store a function during execution

Tags: python-3.x, function

I have a function that I modify frequently. I want to be able to store the exact version of the function used during execution and then use that to recreate the result. Is there a smart way to do that?

Comment: You could just move the varying parts to parameters, then save instances of calls with that set of parameters (`saved = lambda: your_func(arg1, arg2)`). That could also be done with `functools.partial`.

Comment: Correct, the best way would be to have all varying parts as parameters. The issue is that the function is used to prepare data and a lot of calculations are made and, at this stage, it would be too time consuming to build a permanent solution. It is a prototype but I want to be able to go back and recreate the result if I find something interesting.

Comment: I mean, I think your two options really come down to "isolate the changeable parts as parameters" and "make full copies of the functions". For quick testing and prototyping, I've done the latter. It's certainly not *great*, but it works. You could also consider using `git` branches to save the different versions.

Comment: Thanks, I'm working on extracting the function from the .py and store the function in another .py. I agree, it will work but it is not a great solution.